# What is the definition behind `%0 | %0`?

Tags: batch-file

Please help me to find the definition behind this code:

```
%0 | %0
```

If we save this code in a .bat file and run it our CPU & MEMORY usage will go to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

`%n` is the n-th argument when calling a program or batch file. `%0` will be the first parameter or the file name of the executatble/script. Hence `%0` will run it's own file, and the copy will again run it's own. This continues forever and cannot exit